# colab : model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq', 'roberta.large') error

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, roberta-language-model

I tried the code below.

```
import torch

model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq', 'roberta.large')
```

I got the error below.

[image]

I searched tutorial colab for RoBERTa already, however, it does not work either.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/pytorch.github.io/blob/master/assets/hub/pytorch_fairseq_roberta.ipynb

Does any one have save issue? or have any solution for this?